# rock paper scissors stuck in while loop

Tags: python, function

I am making rock, paper, scissors.

After 3 wins or losses, I want it to leave the while loop but it keeps running.

```
##################
# import modules #
##################

from random import randint

# Declaration of variables #

pcCounter, counter = 0, 0
choice = ""
pc = 0

################
# Main program #
################
print("Welcome to Dags Rock,Paper,Scissors")
print("We will be playing a best out of 5")
choice = input("Select rock, paper or scissors")

while counter != 3 or pcCounter != 3:
    if choice == "rock" or choice == "Rock":
        pc = randint(1,3)
        if pc == 1:
            print("You have tied")
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
        elif pc == 2:
            print("You have lost, Paper beats rock")
            pcCounter += 1
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
        else:
            print("You have won, rock beats scissors")
            counter += 1
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
    elif choice == "paper" or choice == "Paper":
        pc = randint(1,3)
        if pc == 1:
            print("You have won, paper beats rock")
            counter += 1
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
        elif pc == 2:
            print("You have tied")
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
        else:
            print("You have lost, scissors beats paper")
            pcCounter += 1
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
    else:
        pc = randint(1,3)
        if pc == 1:
            print("You have lost, rock beats scissors")
            pcCounter += 1
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
        elif pc == 2:
            print("You have won, scissors beats paper")
            Counter += 1
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
        else:
            print("You have tied")
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
#Checks if you won or lost            
if counter == 3:
    print("Congratz you won :)")
else:
    print("Darn you lost :(")enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` test isn't right.  Change:

```
while counter != 3 or pcCounter != 3:
```

to:

```
while counter != 3 and pcCounter != 3:
```

You want to continue the loop only if neither counter is 3.

Comment: Yup that was the problem, thanks a ton, just a beginners mistake i guess :D

Comment: Note that there's an additional bug that was pointed out by Shivin:  In one place you have `Counter += 1` rather than `counter += 1`.  Case is significant, so that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your else condition why is counter variable with capital 'C'? shouldn't it be counter?

```
else:
        pc = randint(1,3)
        if pc == 1:
            print("You have lost, rock beats scissors")
            pcCounter += 1
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
        elif pc == 2:
            print("You have won, scissors beats paper")
            Counter += 1
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
        else:
            print("You have tied")
            choice = input("Enter either rock, paper or scissors")
```

Comment: That as not the root of the problem but that was a good catch, thanks a ton :)